# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, asynchronous, labjs

I am getting the error specified in the question title for the following code snippet :

```
$LAB.queue(function init() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '00000000',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        logging: '0'
    });
}
if(window.FB) {
    init();
} else {
    window.fbAsyncInit = init
});
```

Any ideas as to what might be causing the error? I just cannot figure out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to call init anywhere in your script, define it separately and suppy it to your `queue()` call. Also please change your question to indicate your requirement rather than just saying you need help fixing syntax error...

```
var init = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '00000000',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        logging: '0'
    });
};

$LAB.queue(init);

if(window.FB) {
    init();
} else {
    window.fbAsyncInit = init
}
```

Comment: The last closing parentheses and following semicolon are invalid. Also, call to init() from outside the queue function isn't possible.